# cupy.cuda.cudnn.CuDNNError: CUDNN_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR

Tags: ubuntu, cupy, chainer

My cupy and chainer versions are as follows

> Chainer: 4.1.0 NumPy: 1.15.4 CuPy:   CuPy Version          : 4.1.0
>   CUDA Root             : /usr/local/cuda-9.0   CUDA Build Version    :
>   9000   CUDA Driver Version   : 9020   CUDA Runtime Version  : 9000
>   cuDNN Build Version   : 7104   cuDNN Version         : 7104   NCCL
>   Build Version    : 2104

I am trying to run a test script following [this link](https://github.com/Bartzi/loans) and the script i used is as following

> python image_sheeping.py figure_skating/models/resnet_50_augmentation_no_noise_75_100/Resnet50SheepLocalizer_97305.npz \log -i figure_skating/evaluation_dataset/test_images/22.png -g 0 -o validation_data/images/analyzed

Error message I am receiving is

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "image_sheeping.py", line 50, in 
>       bboxes, scores = localizer.localize(processed_image)[:2]
>     File "/home/rahul/Desktop/Thesis/code/loans/loans/sheep/unsupervised_sheep_localizer.py", line 43, in localize
>       bboxes, rois, scores, visual_backprop = self.model.predict([processed_image], return_visual_backprop=return_visual_backprop)
>     File "/home/rahul/Desktop/Thesis/code/loans/loans/figure_skating/models/resnet_50_augmentation_no_noise_75_100/localizer.py", line 102, in predict
>       rois, bboxes = self(images)
>     File "/home/rahul/Desktop/Thesis/code/loans/loans/figure_skating/models/resnet_50_augmentation_no_noise_75_100/localizer.py", line 144, in **call**
>       h = self.feature_extractor(input_images, layers=['res5', 'pool5'])
>     File "/home/rahul/.virtualenvs/loans/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chainer/links/model/vision/resnet.py", line 198, in **call**
>       h = func(h)
>     File "/home/rahul/.virtualenvs/loans/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chainer/links/connection/convolution_2d.py", line 175, in **call**
>       groups=self.groups)
>     File "/home/rahul/.virtualenvs/loans/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chainer/functions/connection/convolution_2d.py", line 582, in convolution_2d
>       y, = fnode.apply(args)
>     File "/home/rahul/.virtualenvs/loans/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chainer/function_node.py", line 258, in apply
>       outputs = self.forward(in_data)
>     File "/home/rahul/.virtualenvs/loans/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chainer/function_node.py", line 367, in forward
>       return self.forward_gpu(inputs)
>     **File "/home/rahul/.virtualenvs/loans/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chainer/functions/connection/convolution_2d.py", line 161, in forward_gpu
>       return self._forward_cudnn(x, W, b, y)
>     File "/home/rahul/.virtualenvs/loans/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chainer/functions/connection/convolution_2d.py", line 234, in _forward_cudnn
>       auto_tune=auto_tune, tensor_core=tensor_core)
>     File "cupy/cudnn.pyx", line 598, in cupy.cudnn.convolution_forward
>     File "cupy/cudnn.pyx", line 33, in cupy.cudnn.get_handle
>     File "cupy/cuda/cudnn.pyx", line 473, in cupy.cuda.cudnn.create
>     File "cupy/cuda/cudnn.pyx", line 446, in cupy.cuda.cudnn.check_status
>   cupy.cuda.cudnn.CuDNNError: CUDNN_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR**
>   Exception ignored in: del of   0%|                                                     | 0/1 [00:17
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/rahul/.virtualenvs/loans/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tqdm/_tqdm.py", line 931, in **del**
>       self.close()
>     File "/home/rahul/.virtualenvs/loans/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tqdm/_tqdm.py", line 1133, in close
>       self._decr_instances(self)
>     File "/home/rahul/.virtualenvs/loans/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tqdm/_tqdm.py", line 496, in _decr_instances
>       cls.monitor.exit()
>     File "/home/rahul/.virtualenvs/loans/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tqdm/_monitor.py", line 52, in exit
>       self.join()
>     File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1053, in join
>       raise RuntimeError("cannot join current thread")
>   RuntimeError: cannot join current thread

Can anyone help me to solve the error ?

Comment: One possible recommendation for a cuDNN library internal error like this is to file a bug with NVIDIA at developer.nvidia.com with complete instructions for demonstrating the issue.

Comment: Could you try again with CuPy installed using `pip install cupy-cuda90` instead of `pip install cupy`?

Comment: @KenichiMaehashi ....... I have tried both its showing the same error

Answer (score 1):

Could you rerun the code with the following environment variable set?

```
export CUDNN_LOGDEST_DBG=cudnn_debug.log
export CUDNN_LOGINFO_DBG=1
```

Then please share the `cudnn_debug.log` file (e.g. using Gist).